# How can this Python code homework be completed?

Tags: python, random

How can I complete this Python homework question?

> Complete the following assignment statement with the proper random command (either randint or randrange) to simulate the roll of a single six-sided die.
>
> die = _______________

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

if all you're trying to do is store a random number from 1-6 inside the variable `die` then:

```
import random   

die = random.randint(1,6)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
from random import randint
die = randint(1, 6)
```